# How to list every file that is written to, on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find, mtime

What is the best way of getting a list of all files which have been written to, since power on?

Is a simple `find` (with mtime) best for this, or are there other ways?

(`find` won't list files which are written to, then deleted.)

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 12.04, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you're trying to do (and why)? I think that context will help in shaping an appropriate answer.

Comment: @ewwhite I'm installing Linux on (not from) USB flash and want to mount `tmpfs` (or physical HDDs) on frequently written paths, to prolong the media's life.  I don't want the fuss of going fully read-only (`aufs`, etc.).

Comment: Auditing is your friend http://serverfault.com/questions/320716/find-out-which-process-is-changing-a-file/320718#320718

Comment: @chrisdew See, that's a very specialized use case, where the normal answers to run `auditd` may not make sense. Thanks for the clarification. You should add that to the initial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could answer this with special **[auditd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd)** rules tailored to the specific situation, following some metering of a test system/workload, but I don't think that's the most scalable approach... Plus, there's the write load of actually *auditing* the system :)

I would instead rely on higher-quality [SLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell#Single-level_cell) USB flash (versus [MLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell)) for this application. A purpose-built drive like the [**sTec SLC USB drive**](http://www.stec-inc.com/products/usb-flash-drive/) would be my first choice, as it's rated for industrial and embedded applications. The characteristics of SLC flash should counter any concerns about workload or device lifespan.