# What is using php_error.log in /var/log on my Nginx server

Tags: nginx, php.ini

On my Nginx server in /var/log there is php5-fpm.log and php_error.log
The php_error.log has all kind of notices so that it's size grows to hundreds of Mb's. I tried to find which php.ini managed this file, but no luck.

```
php --ini
```

gives:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-geoip.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-horde_lz4.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-ldap.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-memcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mongo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pspell.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-sasl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-tidy.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini
```

The /etc/php5/cli/php.ini is set to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

From the browser, phpinfo(); says that /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini is used, this is also set to `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

After setting this values I did a `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Still all kind of notices and stack traces,
Any idea where this logfile comes from?

Comment: Check the notices and see what scripts are issuing them. Then look what kind of PHP process is running those scripts and what configs is it using.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/320716/find-out-which-process-is-changing-a-file/320718#320718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you first need to check which php-fpm.conf file the php-fpm service is using.

`sudo ps -aux | grep "php-fpm"`

It will show the configuration file it is using.

Go to that path. e.g. /etc/php5/fpm and edit php-fpm.conf to disable logging.

Inside /etc/php5/fpm/www there is another .conf file disable logging on that too.

Comment: Hi,

ps -aux | grep "php-fpm" gives:
root      3788  0.0  0.0  11740   936 pts/0    S+   13:01   0:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
www-data  5858  0.0  9.2 480084 94112 ?        S    Aug26   2:49 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 11182  0.0  8.2 475236 84044 ?        S    Aug26   2:28 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 29016  0.0  5.9 465972 60104 ?        S    Aug29   0:51 php-fpm: pool www

No path is shown?

Comment: It will show like this `root     18889  0.0  0.4 254312 18360 ?        Ss   Aug11   4:18 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php-fpm.conf)`. Check for the master fpm process.

Comment: Try `sudo ps -aux | grep "fpm"`

Comment: Again the output is like in above comment, so after php-fpm: pool www

Comment: Sometimes it uses fpm configuration from /etc/php/ you can see different version of php exists. Or it can be /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf and pool.d/www.conf file , where you can disable and comment the logging.