# Logging changes to file change/modify attributes

Tags: auditd, timestamp

System is Centos8

I need to determine what process is `touch`ing a file without making any changes in content.  I've tried `auditctl` but it does not seem to have a filesystem watch that can track these attributes.

```
sudo auditctl -w /boot/grub2/grubenv -p a -k GRUBENV
```

but this does not capture timestamp changes.

Is there a way to log changes to file modify/change timestamps that do not alter anything else about the file?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/320716/find-out-which-process-is-changing-a-file has a nice example as per Romeo's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp change is more like write operation. So the command should look like:

```
sudo auditctl -w /boot/grub2/grubenv -p wa -k GRUBENV
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this and report back after the next spurious timestamp change.

Comment: The process touching grubenv is `systemd`, which is executing `/usr/sbin/grub2-set-bootflag`.  Why this is happening will merit a new question unless I can find something explaining why `systemd` is doing this regularly.